# Need to Delete Files in Zip Files

Tags: batch-file, zip, archive

Im trying to create one batch file that will recursively search in multiples directories and delete files that are older than "1000" days old.

For regular files this part i have down and written and works.

My issue is trying to create a Batch script that will recussively search the same directories as above and look inside the tons of archive (.zip) files that are in these dirs and delete the files in the zip file and the zip file itself if it meets the required time frame.

The problem is the zip files have newer modified dates (i.e. with in the last week).  The files in the zip files are over that "1000" days old.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: so, your question is "can I delete files older than x days in zip files". The answer is, yes, you can, but it isn't simple. You need to list all content of the zip `7z l file.zip` check the age of each file, create a temp file with the names of the files older than x days, and then delete the files `7z d %%f`. Running the above code for all zips in a dir is trivial `for /r %%a in (*.zip)`

Comment: Yes you are correct, i want to delete the files inside multiple archive files if the files are older than so many days.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post your code attempts and ask a concrete question, we'll be happy to help.